# How to set $! in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to write some functions in perl that set $! in a similar way to the built in perl functions. When I try to do this it complains that 'Argument "Cannot create admin user" isn't numeric in scalar assignment'. I have tried googling this but unfortunately google won't watch on $! so results are difficult to come by.

```
if(!createUser('admin')) { print $!; }

sub createUser
{
  my ($user) = @_;
  if($user eq "admin")
  {
    $! = "Cannot create admin user";
    return 0;
  }
  #create user here
  return 1;
}
```

PS. I know about Try::Tiny etc but I want to maintain consistancy with the rest of the script, if I switch to try/catch I want to move the entire script across which I am not ready to do.

Comment: I don't think you can do this.  Why do you want to?

Comment: If you want to to return non-system messages, either use $@ or a global in your module's namespace (e.g. `$DBI::errstr`).

Comment: @squiguy I just want to write code that works similar to perl functions for the sake of consistency. I guess it's difficult for me to write consistent code if perl itself isn't consistent though :-) It seems that some functions die, others return $!, some return $@ and others have a special variable.

Comment: It's worth noting that the way Perl functions work is not really considered to be good anymore (hence `autodie`); they continue to work that way in large part for the sake of backwards compatibility.  Writing new code to conform to the cutting edge programming practices of 1993 is a bad thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$!` is a magic variable that corresponds to the numerical error codes of your operating system (`errno` in the Unix-y `libc` libraries, something else like `GetLastError()` from `kernel32.dll` in Windows).

You can only set it to a number. When Perl wants to use it in a string context, it converts it to an appropriate text error message.

Example:

```
$! = 4;
print $!, "\n";
print 0+$!, "\n";
```

Produces (on my system, anyway):

```
Interrupted system call
4
```

It is perfectly appropriate (if non-portable, since different systems are free to use different integer values to represent standard error codes) to set `$!` to correspond to some standard error on your system:

```
sub my_do_something_with_file {
    my $file = shift;
    if (! -f $file) {
        $! = 2; # "No such file or directory" on my system
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

But there is no facility to create your own custom error messages to be returned with `$!`.

Comment: Maybe some more examples? I think, that people want to know more about  this kind of Perl magic (duality of variable) ;)

Comment: `$%` and `$=` can only be assigned integer values. `$-` can only be assigned non-negative integer values. `$?` can only be assigned integer values on the range -1 to 65335. Handy tips for code golf.

Comment: @loldop Such people are hereby referred to `perldoc perlvar`:  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Answer (score 4):

As documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), `$!` contains a C `errno`, which is a number.  Textual Perl-level error messages appear in `$@`, which is *usually* set by `die`.  I would *not* recommend setting it manually, not least because it's a transpackage global.

Just use `Try::Tiny` if that's what you need.  If the rest of the script is written poorly, you don't gain much from being consistent with it.

Comment: I guess I will start using Try::Tiny. The issue I have is that I presume stuff like `try { print $fh "abc"; }` won't get caught if the file system fills up for example. It doesn't have the consistency I would like.

Comment: you can `use autodie;` to make builtins die on failure instead of returning a flag

Answer (score 1):

You can set $! to a numeric value that happens to match a C errno value and that sets the expected string value. Unfortunately this is not very portable.

If $! was not a magic variable you could assign a dual numeric/string value using dualvar(), which is available in Scalar::Util, which is a core package.

```
use Scalar::Util qw(dualvar) ; 
my $x = dualvar( 44, "Hello, world" );
print "string=$x,  number=" . (0+$x), "\n"
```

But with $! only the number survived my prior attempts.